# Debug ZF2 App on PHPCloud

Tags: php, zend-framework2, cloud

I'm experimenting with deploying my ZF2 application to different cloud environments.

Just signed up for Zend's PHP Cloud, added it as a remote repository, and pushed my code there.  When I go to the home page it displays as expected, but that's it.  When I try to access any of my application links I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at myapplication.my.phpcloud.com Port 80
```

Now, I think this is an Apache error, does that sound right?  And if so, how can I trouble shoot it?

I see that I can tunnel into the application container, but I don't have access to the operating system.  Normally in this case (when working on a local linux server) I would look at the log files and find out what the problem is.  How can I do that in the PHPCloud?

Thanks!

Comment: http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/03/25/ftpftps-and-file-management-in-java-and-php-cloud-hosting/#4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I went back to Ubuntu on EC2.  Perhaps IaaS is the way to go for the moment, not PaaS?